# jQuery Datatable Conditional Settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am wondering if there is a way to conditionally set properties on a jQuery DataTable and thus avoid repeating nearly identical table conversion calls with duplicate properties.

For example, I have a table that I want to provide an Excel export button on if a certain boolean is true, but don't provide it if that boolean is false.

```
if blnExport {
    $('#tblDetail').DataTable({
        bPaginate: false,
        aaSorting: [],
        language: { emptyTable: "No Results Found" },
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: 'Export to Excel',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
            } 
        }]
    });
}    
else {
    $('#tblDetail').DataTable({
        bPaginate: false,
        aaSorting: [],
        language: { emptyTable: "No Results Found" }
    });
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with one conversion call? Thanks.

Comment: What is the condition, what is the code if an excel button is to be shown and what is the code if it is not shown?

Comment: The code in my question is how I am currently handling this. If blnExport is true then I create a datatable with an excel export button. If blnExport is false, I create a datatable without an excel button. Here's my question. Is there a way to just have one datatable conversion and then set some of the properties based on certain conditions? That way I don't have to duplicate properties that will be the same regardless of what blnExport is. In this case, I want to include the excel button if blnExport is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have a `function` like this:

```
function myFunction(params) {
    //Do something
}
```

Let's consider this example:

```
var input = {
    a: 1;
};

if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)) {
    input.b = 2;
}

myFunction(input);
```

As you can see in the example, `a` is always a member of `input`, but we randomize whether `b` should be in it. Basically, the idea is to:

- create the `input` object with what you surely need
- check what is needed and add it
- pass it to the `function`

Let's apply this to your specific case:

```
var input = {
    bPaginate: false,
    aaSorting: [],
    language: { emptyTable: "No Results Found" }
};

if (blnExport) {
    input.dom = 'Bfrtip';
    input.buttons = [{
        extend: 'excel',
        text: 'Export to Excel',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
        } 
    }];
}
$('#tblDetail').DataTable(input);
```